# Mediation using normalized variables

Tags: normalization, mediation

If I normalize (range 0-1) variables x, m, y prior to conduct a mediation (OLS), do I report them as "fully normalized coefficients". How do I interpret the results? I am used to report unstandardized results, but some reviewers prefer normalized (0-1) results.

Comment: Do you mean given some variables, scale them to (0,1) range. Use those transformed variables for regression?

Comment: Yes. Hayes (2013) prefers the unstandardized results, but sometimes reviewers have questions such as "How many units of change in Y represent a unit of change in X?" I don't know if I can interpret a resulting coefficient of, say, .03, as meaning 3% of change. What are normalized (0-1) are the variable values, not the relationship between them.